# Delete a specific document, not the all Firestrore collection

Tags: swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, datatable

There is a table view that displays a collection of user flowers.
When user goes to detail VC, he can see information about the selected flower, also there is a "Delete" button, the problem is that I only found how to delete all flowers (all collection MyFlowers),

```
db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).collection("MyFlowers").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
          if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
          } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
              document.reference.delete()
            }
          }
        }
```

but I want delete only selected flower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a specific document, you'll need to know the ID of that document or something else that uniquely identifies the specific document.

So you'll need to take the document ID that you pass to the VC and use that in the call to delete the specific document:

```
db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)
  .collection("MyFlowers").document("idOfTheDocumentToDelete")
  .delete()
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how to take this id, this is the random number which creates when user add a flower to "MyFlowers"

Comment: How do you pass the random number for the selected flower from the main view to the detail view? The same way you do that, you can then also make it available in your code that deletes the selected flower.

Comment: There are two collections in Firestore: Flowers and Users, when user add flower from AllFlowers its create new collection inside current user with all flowers added, and this documents has a random numbers https://ibb.co/gmSgyMP

Comment: That makes sense. But when the user "goes to detail VC" in your question, how do you know what flower detail to show? Essentially: you must know **something** of the flower to delete. Firestore can't make that up for you, it has to come from within the app flow already.

Comment: For the moment I did it with this code: whereField("timeID", isEqualTo: flovers?.myFloverTimer as Any).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in if let err = err { print("Error getting documents: (err)") } else { for document in querySnapshot!.documents { document.reference.delete() so, it takes id of notifications and delete flower, is this the only solution?

Comment: To delete (or write to) a document you need to know the complete path to that document, including its ID. If you don't have the ID of the document, but know something else that uniquely identified is, you can use a query to find the document ID, and then delete it.